# Get Random number of lines from textfile with group by

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get random number of lines(let's say 2 ) group by Code from text file.

for e.g.

4581511:            50.27:             AT
1223522:            86.99:             AT
7456117:            68.59:             QW
5261789:            39.17:            QW
.....
.....

### Text File

bookNumber         Price         Code
4581511:            50.27:             AT
7841522:            26.13:             AT
7353532:             96.13:            AT
1223522:            86.99:             AT
8415621:             89.70:            IT
8411442:            82.42:             IT
4555577:             19.14:            IT
7655577:             65.45:            IT
2754831:            35.44:             DR
1364449:            82.47:           DR
4545454:            45.65:           DR
8795457:            78.36:            DR
5261789:            39.17:            QW
7845522:            10.42:             QW
7456117:            68.59:             QW
4346129:             23.78:            QW

I got this far and I am geting 2 lines which are not random but in sequence

#### Code

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
    {

        using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(":"))
                {
                    yield return line;
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetrandomLines()
    {

        string filepath = "file location";
        var readTextFile = ReadLines(filepath);
        var codeGroup = readTextFile.GroupBy(line => line.Substring(line.Length - 2))
                          .Select(g => new
                          {
                            value = g.Key,
                            count = g.Count()
                           });


        foreach (var item in codeGroup)
        {
            Random randomLineGenerator = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
             var randomLines = (from x in readTextFile
                                where x.Substring(x.Length - 2) == item.value
                                select x).Skip(randomLineGenerator.Next(0, item.count)).Take(2);
             foreach (var line in randomLines)
             {
                 yield return line;
             }
        }

    }
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guid version, the random values can't be the same.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetrandomLines2(string filePath, int lines)
{
    return ReadLines(filePath)
        .GroupBy(line => line.Substring(line.Length - 2))
        .SelectMany(s => s.OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(lines));
}
```

Random version, the two random values may be the same.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTwoRandomLines(string filePath)
{
    var codeGroup = ReadLines(filePath)
        .GroupBy(line => line.Substring(line.Length - 2));

    Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

    foreach (var item in codeGroup)
    {
        yield return item.Skip(rnd.Next(item.Count())).FirstOrDefault();
        yield return item.Skip(rnd.Next(item.Count())).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetRandomLines(string path, int lines)
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path).OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(lines))
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only works for first Code which is AT , what about others??

Comment: Hi BFree
I run your code with below and return only 2 lines 
 GetRandomLines("c:\.., 2);
what i want is 2 random lines   per Code(i.e. AT,IT,DR and QW )
thx